# How to I use std::swap with array?

Tags: c++

```
 class MoveSkill : public Skill {
public:
    int step;   // kaç adım yer değişecek, - ise geriye + ise ileriye
    MoveSkill(int step);

public:
    virtual void Use(std::vector<Unit*> units, int userIndex, int onUsing);
     };
 MoveSkill::MoveSkill(int step) : Skill(std::vector<int>{0,1}, std::vector<int>{1,2,3}, "moveskill") {
    this->step = step;
}

void MoveSkill::Use(std::vector<Unit*> units, int userIndex, int onUsing) {     // Eğer karakter doğru sınırlardaysa, karakterlerin yerlerini değiştir..
    if (userIndex > 3 && userIndex < 8) {
        int swapIndex = step + userIndex;
        if (swapIndex >= 4 || swapIndex <= 7) {
            std::swap(units[userIndex], units[swapIndex]);
            std::cout << units[swapIndex]->GetName() << " ile " << units[userIndex]->GetName() << " yer degistirdi!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else if (userIndex >= 0) {
        int swapIndex = step + userIndex;
        if (swapIndex >= 0 || swapIndex <= 3) {

            std::swap(units[userIndex], units[swapIndex]);
            std::cout << units[swapIndex]->GetName() << " ile " << units[userIndex]->GetName() << " yer degistirdi!" << std::endl;
            std::cout<< "userindex:" << userIndex << "swapindex:" << swapIndex << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to swap `units[userIndex]` and  `units[swapIndex]`

For example `userIndex=0`  and `swapIndex=1` but writes on the command screen  userindex:  0, swapIndex=1. I want to it write userIndex=1 and swapIndex=0.

how can I do ? Thanks for everything sorry my english.

Answer (score 1):

Swap (manually) the positions in the final output statement.

```
std::swap(units[userIndex], units[swapIndex]);
std::cout << units[swapIndex]->GetName() << " ile "
          << units[userIndex]->GetName() << " yer degistirdi!" << std::endl;
std::cout << "userindex:" << swapIndex 
          << "swapindex:" << userIndex << std::endl;
```

Alternatively, swap `swapIndex` and `userIndex`:

```
std::swap(units[userIndex], units[swapIndex]);
std::swap(userIndex, swapIndex);
std::cout << units[userIndex]->GetName() << " ile "
          << units[swapIndex]->GetName() << " yer degistirdi!" << std::endl;
std::cout << "userindex:" << userIndex
          << "swapindex:" << swapIndex << std::endl;
```

I also suggest changing your output to indicate that these are not the `userIndex` and `swapIndex` variables that were passed into the function, but rather the conceptually-new indices of the user and the thing that user was swapped with:

```
std::cout << "(new) User Index:" << userIndex
          << "(new) Swap Index:" << swapIndex << std::endl;
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have another question: when i use moveskill with crusader2 userindex changing 1 to 2. but when i use it again it print same thing . userindex must be 3.

Comment: If you have another question, open another question. But make sure you explain what `crusader2` is and why you expect `userindex` to be 3 in that case.